# Java FX app - unique id for each distibution

Tags: javafx

I have Java FX app which is available for download on my site. I am looking for a way how to remotely and uniquely identify each downloaded application. Is it possible to store the id (for ex. in txt file) into a package of the Java FX app immediately before download?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: A jar file is basically a zip file. You could store the jar file without the text file containing the id, then on each request (I am assuming you are using some Java servlet-based web technology, though you could do this with other technologies), create the id, create a `ZipOutputStream` to send data back to the client, create a `ZipEntry` to contain the text file with the id, send that entry to the zip output stream, then just iterate over the zip entries in the exiting jar file and send each one to the `ZipOutputStream`. Never tried that, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I wonder if there is a more "prettier" solution or if having a file with id is the standard solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you distribute it, you could try [signing and timestamping the jar file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html) for distribution. That way you can ensure that the file is not tampered with and [validate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/verify.html) it's signature and timestamp either locally or in a callback to a service you provide if necessary.

> Also consider [java-webstart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-webstart) cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Yes, signing and webstart technologies can be used together if desired.  Those two technologies can be used separately or together, so you can choose what is appropriate for your app.  See the [javapackager documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packaging.html) for more details of the packaging process for web start (go through the documentation and refer to the sections that reference jnlp).  Be aware that web start currently only works with Oracle JDK (as far as I know).

For your purposes, you would create a script that executes on each download request to generate a [unique id](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) or timestamp (or gets a timestamp from a timestamp service) and adds that to the package before signing and offering the package for download.  You could add the download instance UUID and timestamp together with the referring IP address or user id (if you have a login system on your website), to a server-side database to track who downloaded what at what time.

If using webstart, you use a JNLP deployment as mentioned in the linked documentation.  There are options for the packaging the JNLP to interact with some Javascript on a webpage, which can reduce network traffic and speed up the download and usage process.  Sophisticated deployment mechanisms can dynamically generate that download package, and the download page with Javascript calls which embed JNLP data.  Details or samples of such systems are outside the scope of the information I can provide here.